# Can I edit Demo account details in app review information in iTunes Connect when app status is “Waiting for Review”?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I have resubmitted my app for review after Apple rejection due to metadata rejection.

I have updated the details in "Notes". Now my app status is "Waiting for Review". I want to change the demo account details.

Can I update the "Demo Account" details when the app status is "Waiting for Review"?

[image]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can change all the metadata until your app is In Review.